# Copying array of objects into another array is it reference type in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have a array of objects `TransactionVModel.FiltersList[]`.
When I copy this array to another array `fltrList[]` and if I modify any of the object in array `fltrList` will it get reflect in Array `TransactionVModel.FiltersList` in JQuery ? For better clarity below is my example. As per me since it is a reference type it should update array `TransactionVModel.FiltersList` as well but in my scenario it is not happening, can I know why it is not happening ?

`TransactionVModel.FiltersList` is declared as `ko.observableArray();` in my code.

```
function UpdateSelectedFilters(data) {
    var fltrList = [];
    fltrList = TransactionVModel.FiltersList();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
      var index = fltrList.indexOf(data[i]);
      if (index != -1) {
        var fltrObj = fltrList[index];
        var fltrValArr = [];
        fltrValArr = data.valueItems;
        for (var j = 0; j < fltrValArr.length; j++) {
        if (fltrValArr[j].IsSelected == true) {
        if (fltrObj.indexOf(fltrValArr[j]) != -1) {
            var selectedVal = fltrObj[fltrObj.indexOf(fltrValArr[j])];
            selectedVal.IsSelected = true;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

In my scenario I am updating `selectedVal.IsSelected` property but it is not reflecting the observableArray `TransactionVModel.FiltersList`.

Comment: Are you sure that code actually sets `selectedVal`? It's in three levels of conditional code, so just making sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell knockout that your array has changed with `valueHasMutated`:

```
function UpdateSelectedFilters(data) {
    var fltrList = [];
    fltrList = TransactionVModel.FiltersList();
    //...
    TransactionVModel.FiltersList.valueHasMutated();
}
```